# IIS Rule Excption Issue

Tags: iis, web-config

We recently migrated our domain from [www.mohavecounty.us](http://www.mohavecounty.us) to [www.mohave.gov](http://www.mohave.gov).  So I wrote a rule that redirects anything that comes from [www.mohavecounty.us](http://www.mohavecounty.us) to [www.mohave.gov](http://www.mohave.gov).

The only caveat is that I need to have an exception for two URLs due to a software license tied to our original domain.  So when I go to [www.mohavecounty.us/console](http://www.mohavecounty.us/console), I don't want it going to [www.mohave.gov/console](http://www.mohave.gov/console).  The rule is working as expected for everything but the exception.

```
<rule name="Redirect To mohave.gov" enabled="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
    
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mohavecounty.us$" />
    
                
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/console(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Login.aspx(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mohave.gov/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

When I go to wwww.mohavecounty.us/console the page load properly, but when I look at the Chrome dev tools, I noticed that some files are coming from [www.mohave.gov](http://www.mohave.gov)

[image]

The problem is that when I try to log in, its telling me that that the service I'm trying to contact is being blocked because it is a cross-domain exception.

[image]

So looking at the network tab in chrome and it seems like some files are loaded on [www.mohave.gov](http://www.mohave.gov) domain instead of [www.mohavecounty.us](http://www.mohavecounty.us) domain.  I understand the reason of the problem, but what I dont understand is why are those files being loaded under [www.mohave.gov](http://www.mohave.gov) instead of [www.mohavecounty.us](http://www.mohavecounty.us).  None of the paths in question are hard coded to the domain.

I tried to seperate the exeption rule into another rule for the path console:

```
<rule name="ignore web forms folder 3" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
    <match url="^console$" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

but it's not working either.

If anyone can please help with what is wrong with my rule.

Comment: You need to figure out which files are coming from mohave.gov. Then check the failed request tracing logs of these files. It will record the process of rewrite.

Comment: None of the files are coming directly from mohave.gov.  I don't hard code the domain

Comment: Do you mean that it is empty under mohave.go item?